# Правильное формирование фото галереи

Tags: jquery, css3, html, javascript

[Пример сайта](http://www.nickrosephotography.com/weddings/)

На данном сайте мы видим как сформирована галерея изображений. А точнее как она представлена пользователю. Здесь установлен jS плагин. Который корректирует вывод изображений т.к. они имеют разный формат. В итоге мы получаем целостную картинку. Средствами CSS и HTML у меня такого не вышло. А в поиске затрудняюсь найти нужный JS, Jquery код.  Буду очень признателен, если кто-то подскажет в каком направлении двигаться и где искать, возможно подскажите статью где описаны способы реализации. Спасибо.

Comment: > А в поиске затрудняюсь найти нужный JS, Jquery код

И [так][1] тоже? И [так][2]?


  [1]: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=jquery%20gallery
  [2]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=jquery%20gallery

Comment: Это похоже на [Masonry][1]. По крайней мере, вполне подойдет для вашей задачи.

   [1]:http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Afimida, я там дополнил еще парой "плюшек"...